# Orientdb partitioned graph java implementation

Tags: spring, orientdb, multi-tenant, tinkerpop-blueprint, ops4j

I've got a backend Spring application and Orientdb graph database. I use Tinkerpop Frames to map orientdb vertices to java objects and OPS4J for spring transaction management. Now I want to implement there a multitenancy where several customers (tenants) uses this one application instance. This application completely works on REST principles and it is opened to several Angular applications - each per customer. So there's as many frontend Angular applications as our customers and only one backend REST Spring application. Backend recognize the tenant from a HTTP request.

Now I'm not sure about the best solution...

**First solution**

When I read the Orientdb documentation, I found there a way how to implement multitenancy in orientdb - http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Partitioned-Graphs.html. However I don't know how to use it through the Java API unless I don't want to create a new database connection for each request. Because right now the spring transaction manager takes connections from connection pool which is centrally set in Spring transaction management configuration. I didn't find any Java example to this.

Spring transaction management config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionConfig {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("graphDbTx")
    public OrientTransactionManager graphDbTransactionManager() {
        OrientTransactionManager bean = new OrientTransactionManager();
        bean.setDatabaseManager(graphDatabaseFactory());
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public OrientBlueprintsGraphFactory graphDatabaseFactory() {
        OrientBlueprintsGraphFactory dbf = new OrientBlueprintsGraphFactory();
        dbf.setMaxPoolSize(6);
        dbf.setUrl(DbConfig.DATABASE_URL);
        dbf.setUsername("admin");
        dbf.setPassword("admin");
        return dbf;
    }

    @Bean
    public FramedGraphFactory framedGraphFactory() {
        return new FramedGraphFactory(new JavaHandlerModule());
    }

}
```

Getting connection:

```
protected FramedGraph<OrientGraph> framedGraph() {
    return framedGraphFactory.create(gdbf.graph());
}
```

**Second solution**

Another solution is to use the Tinkerpop

> PartitionGraph

class which works on Orientdb but I didn't find any sentence about this possibility in Orientdb documentation. Just this in Tinkerpop - https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Partition-Implementation. It works but in the end it just creates a not indexed property in every orientdb vertex so I'm afraid about performance of querying here.

Does anyone have any experiences with this? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Java API to create a partitioned DB (if I understand what you're interested in) macro steps are:

- get connection (using the pool the istance of db are reused);
- modify class V and E;  create new user enable to write;
- when you log in the  db, user1 can write Vertices, invisible to the
  user2 and    contrary;

  //WRITE IN YOUR CONTROLLER: CREATE USER ENABLE TO WRITE ON DB ..............
      Connection con = new Connection();
      OrientGraph noTx = con.getConnection();

  ```
  //create partition
      noTx.begin();
      noTx.command(new OCommandSQL("ALTER CLASS V superclass orestricted")).execute();
      noTx.command(new OCommandSQL("ALTER CLASS E superclass orestricted")).execute();
      noTx.commit();

      //create different users
      noTx.begin();
      String ridRule = "";
      Iterable<Vertex> rule = noTx.command(new OCommandSQL("select from ORole where name = 'writer'")).execute();
      ridRule = rule.iterator().next().getId().toString();
      noTx.command(new OCommandSQL("INSERT INTO ouser SET name = 'user1', status = 'ACTIVE', password = 'user1', roles = ["+ridRule+"]")).execute();
      noTx.command(new OCommandSQL("INSERT INTO ouser SET name = 'user2', status = 'ACTIVE', password = 'user2', roles = ["+ridRule+"]")).execute();
      noTx.commit();

      //will not close the graph instance, but will keep open and available for the next requester
      noTx.shutdown();

      //finally To release all the instances and free all the resources
      con.clodeAllConnect();


      //WRITE IN YOUR CONTROLLER: LOGIN WITH USER APPROPRIATE .....................
      //CODE to login with user1 or user2,  CREATE VERTEX SET label = 'food', name = 'Pizza' etc....
  }


  //beans 
  public static class Connection {

      private OrientGraphFactory factory = null;

      public Connection() {
          //recyclable pool of instances 
          factory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:localhost/blog").setupPool(1, 10);
      }

      //return the connection 
      public OrientGraph getConnection() {
          OrientGraph txGraph = factory.getTx();
          return txGraph;
      }

      public void clodeAllConnect(){
          factory.close();

      }
  }
  ```

To adapt these steps and insert them in Spring might be useful this link that is [OrientDB - spring implementation](https://github.com/orientechnologies/spring-data-orientdb). it isn't much but I hope will be of help.

Comment: Yes, I know that when I log with user1 (tenant1), he can write vertices which are not visible to other users (tenants) and I know how to do it on such a low level of java implementation. But I don't want to write my own transaction manager - it's quite complicated and I don't have much time. But I'm afraid I'll have to do a pull request to OPS4J transaction maanger which works just fine for one tenant, but it's not ready for more tenants and implement it there. I think the Spring Data Orientdb is still in development phase, there's no stable version isn't it?

Comment: I'll fork the OPS4J project (integrating spring transactions with orientdb) and implement the solution for Orientdb partitioned graphs - similar or maybe same to yours. No one works on that anyway right now. It should not be such a problem, it's a small library.